# Simple C++ vector/pointer gaffe

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

This is definitely really simple.  I have been out of C++ for a few years, so I need some help with figuring out why this won't compile.

I have a class called 'PointList'.  In the header file, I have the following:

```
public:
    PointList();

private:
    std::vector< Point* > *pl;
```

In the .cpp file, I have the following:

```
PointList::PointList()
{
    pl = new vector< Point* >();
}
```

This does not compile.

> Expected type-specifier before 'vector'
>   Cannot convert 'int*' to 'std::vector <*' in assignment
>   expected ';' before 'vector'

What gives?

Comment: Also, if you've been out of C++ for a while, you might want to consider using shared_ptr instead of raw pointers.  People have different opinions on this though :p.

Comment: I haven't seen one who opposes smart pointers and still knows what s/he is talking about..

Comment: Indeed.  But I have seen debates about cache coherency in tight algorithms - particularly with the allocation of the pointer reference count.  Personally I don't use raw pointers at all these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using `using` declarations. If not you need to prefix `vector` with `namespace std::` in your cpp file

Comment: Things don't get much easier than this.  Thank you.  I'll accept this when I am allowed in 9 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to namespace qualify vector:

```
PointList::PointList()
{
    pl = new std::vector< Point* >();
}
```

And, do not abuse pointers in C++. Most probably member `pl` need not be a pointer.

If you need collection of (vector, list, etc) of polymorphic types, take a look at [Boost.PointerContainer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html)